# Struggling to understand the relationship between two definitions of entropy

Tags: clustering, entropy

I am familiar with entropy as defined from information theory, which is simply

$ H(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p(x_{i}) \log p(x_{i}) $,

for a discrete set of probabilities. In term of clustering, the entropy can be used to measure the quality of a clustering solution. It is defined as,

$ E(S_{r}) = - \frac{1}{\log{q}} \sum_{i=1}^{q} \frac{n_{r}^{i}}{n_{r}} \log \frac{n_{r}^{i}}{n_{r}} $,

where $S_{r}$ is a cluster, $q$ is the number of classes in the data set, $n_{r}^{i}$ is the number of documents of the $i$'th class that were assigned to the $r$'th cluster and $n_{r}$ is the size of the cluster. The definition is exactly the same in [Empirical and Theoretical Comparisons of Selected Criterion Functions for Document Clustering](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:MACH.0000027785.44527.d6).

I understand the idea behind why it is used, although I don't understand how we got from the first definition of entropy to the second equation.

Comment: One goes from the first expression to the second by letting $\frac{n_r^i}{n_r}=p(x_i)$, noting that $\log_q(z) = \log(z)/log(q)$, interpreting the $\log$ as $\log_q$, and inserting the minus sign that should be there.

Comment: @whuber, your explanation don't make sense to me. By letting $\frac{n_{r}^{i}}{n_{r}} = p(x_i)$, we get $E(S_r) - \sum_{i=1}^{q}\frac{n_{r}^{i}}{n_{r}}\log{\frac{n_{r}^{i}}{n_{r}}}$.

Comment: @zeferino I'll grant you a missing '=' sign in your comment and I'll insert a common factor of $1/\log(q)$ to account for the base of the logarithm. Now, isn't that *exactly* what is written in the question?

Comment: @whuber Are you saying that the base of the logarithm is $q$ in the first equation or in the second?

Comment: @zeferino When I wrote, "interpreting the $\log$ as $\log_q", that referred to the first equation.  For more about this, please refer to [properties of logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).

Answer (score 3):

The $\dfrac{1}{\log q}$ in the second definition is a normalization factor so that the entropy value is at the interval $[0, 1]$.

Considering the evaluation of a cluster, the entropy is maximum when it presents elements of all classes in the same proportion.

In this case, $n_{r}^{i} = 1$  for $i = 1, \ldots, q$ and $ q = n$. The entropy will be:
\begin{eqnarray}
E(S_r) & = & -\sum_{i=1}^{q}\dfrac{1}{q}\log \dfrac{1}{q} \\
       & = & -\log \dfrac{1}{q} = -(\log 1 - \log q) = \log q\\
\end{eqnarray}

Since the maximum entropy is $\log q$, the second definition used this fact to normalize the entropy of a cluster.